# Create pgsql view who SUM two column from two different table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, view

I have 2 views :

**prognosis_scores**:

| user_id | isGoodPrognosis | pts_won | good_gap | good_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | true | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | true | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | false | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**question_scores**:

| user_id | isGoodPrognosis | pts_won |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | 0 |
| 2 | true | 10 |

And would like to create a third view that would calculate the total points for a user :
(i also need additional data from *users* table)

**score_calculations**:

| user_id | pts__won | good_gap | good_score | good_winner | company_id | team_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | John |
| 2 | 13 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Sam |

To do so, i did this :

```sql
 CREATE VIEW score_calculations
    AS SELECT 
    users.id as user_id,
    users.name as name,
    users.company_id as company_id,
    users.team_id as team_id,
    users.email_verified AS email_verified,
    users.banned AS banned,
    -- users.email as email,
    SUM(COALESCE(prognosis_scores."pts_won", 0) + COALESCE (question_scores."pts_won", 0) ) as pts_won,
    SUM(prognosis_scores."good_gap") as good_gap,
    SUM(prognosis_scores."good_score") as good_score,
    SUM(prognosis_scores."isGoodPrognosis"::INT) as good_winner
    FROM users
    
    LEFT JOIN prognosis_scores
    ON prognosis_scores.user_id=users.id
    LEFT JOIN question_scores
    ON question_scores.user_id=users.id
    GROUP BY users.id , users.name, users.company_id,team_id,email_verified,banned;
```

But the `SUM(COALESCE(prognosis_scores."pts_won", 0) + COALESCE (question_scores."pts_won", 0) ) as pts_won,` did not work well :  [SUM with multiple LEFT JOINS with VIEWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591584/sum-with-multiple-left-joins-with-views)

So i ended up with this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW score_calculations
AS SELECT u.id as user_id, u.name, u.company_id, u.team_id, u.email_verified,u.banned,
-- users.email as email,
   COALESCE(ps.pts_won, 0) + COALESCE (qs.pts_won, 0) as pts_won,
   ps.good_gap, ps.good_score, ps.good_winner
FROM users u LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT SUM(ps."pts_won") as pts_won,
             SUM(ps.good_gap) as good_gap,
             SUM(ps.good_score) as good_score,
             SUM(ps."isGoodPrognosis"::INT) as good_winner
      FROM prognosis_scores ps
      WHERE ps.user_id = u.id
     ) ps
     ON 1=1 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT SUM(qs."pts_won") as pts_won
      FROM question_scores qs
      WHERE qs.user_id = u.id
     ) qs
     ON 1=1;
```

The problem is that the second chunk of code is very slow,  when i try to run `SELECT * FROM score_calculations` the execution time is about 16s while the first chunk of code is fast and the execution time is about 400ms.

For this test i have about 1000 users and about 30000 prognosis_scores

The question is: how can i optimize or change the second chunk of code (score_calculations view) ?

Comment: To diagnose performance issues use EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Include the result of analyzed query to your question to get the best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer tries to optimise query:

```
SELECT * FROM score_calculations
```

Using keyword [LATERAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.10.2) improves performance if you need info on several users, but for all the users not using LATERAL would generally be better in terms of performance.

```
CREATE VIEW score_calculations
AS 
SELECT 
  u.id as user_id, u.name, u.company_id, u.team_id, u.email_verified,u.banned,
-- users.email as email,
   COALESCE(ps.pts_won, 0) + COALESCE (qs.pts_won, 0) as pts_won,
   ps.good_gap, ps.good_score, ps.good_winner
FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      ps.user_id,
      SUM(ps.pts_won) as pts_won,
      SUM(ps.good_gap) as good_gap,
      SUM(ps.good_score) as good_score,
      SUM(ps."isGoodPrognosis"::INT) as good_winner
    FROM 
      prognosis_scores ps
    GROUP BY
      ps.user_id
    ) ps ON (ps.user_id = u.id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      qs.user_id,
      SUM(qs.pts_won) as pts_won
    FROM 
      question_scores qs
    GROUP BY 
      qs.user_id 
    ) qs ON (qs.user_id = u.id);
```

Your original view is good if you use **WHERE** conditions with attributes from `users` table. You should **check if you have indeces** on `prognosis_scores.user_id` and `question_scores.user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

For the lateral joins, you want the following indexes:

- `prognosis_scores(user_id)`
- `question_scores(user_id)`

The indexes are needed to look up the particular rows for a user in these tables -- without them, the database needs to resort to other mechanisms such as a nested loop.

I imagine that with the right indexes, this version might actually be faster than the first version, because it avoids the outer aggregation (no promises on that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (You can add the JOIN with users):

```
SELECT 
    ps.user_id,
    SUM(COALESCE(ps."pts_won", 0) + COALESCE (qs."pts_won", 0) ) as pts_won,
    SUM(ps."good_gap") as good_gap,
    SUM(ps."good_score") as good_score,
    SUM(ps.good_winner) as good_winner

FROM (SELECT ps.user_id,
             SUM(ps."pts_won") AS pts_won,
             SUM(ps."good_gap") as good_gap,
             SUM(ps."good_score") as good_score,
             SUM(ps."isGoodPrognosis"::INT) as good_winner
      FROM prognosis_scores ps
      GROUP BY ps.user_id) AS ps
      
LEFT JOIN question_scores qs ON qs.user_id = ps.user_id
  
GROUP BY ps.user_id 
ORDER BY ps.user_id;
```